# What are all the different ways to rewrite this jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a command like this.

```
.css('display', 'block')
```

However, I think it could also be rewritten in different ways. For example,

```
.css('display : block')
```

That may or may not be correct. I don't remember. Anyways, do you know different ways to rewrite the original command?

Comment: because when I was playing around with these with someone, it turned out that sometimes some browsers didn't support each method

Comment: @mjmitche: Then you made a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set a CSS property in jQuery, there are three methods:

```
.css( propertyName, value )
.css( propertyName, function(index, value) )
.css( map )
```

See the [JQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You mean `.css({display:'block'})` and they are both exactly achieve the same thing. Except with my example you can set multiple css styles.

Comment: They're not "exactly the same" at all.

Comment: @Tomalak How are they different?

Comment: One takes a string as an argument. The other takes an object.

Comment: And they both achieve the same thing don't they? Just different parameters doesn't mean they do different things? Infact its just overloading with different parameters.

Comment: @Amir: In this one, specific, narrow scenario, yes the same CSS property is set to the same value. To suggest that the two approaches are "exactly the same" is misleading; your recent edit to "they exactly _achieve_ the same thing" is better... in _this_ case.

Comment: @Jared: Are we keeping you up?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
$("selector").show();
$("selector").css({display:"block"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.css({display : 'block'})
```

Here is the alternative.
This way you can apply more CSS properties to selected objects.

Answer (score -1):

This is just reaching here, but:

```
<style>
    .i-like-the-taste-of-tofu { color: #29c411 }
</style>

....

<p class="this-is-gon-be-greenish">
    AMERICA IS A COUNTRY AND ALSO MOST OF THE WESTERN HEMISPHERE SO THERE
</p>

....

<script>
    $('#this-is-gon-be-greenish').addclass('i-like-the-taste-of-tofu');
</script>
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the "United States of America", the USA does not constitute "most of the Western hemisphere" at all. Not even close.

Comment: That's just weird. Not to mention you don't need the `.` in the `.addClass()` argument.

Comment: @Tomalak I meant that America has two definitions: the country, and South+North America, which is most of the Western Hemisphere.

Comment: @Jared yeah, I was stretching for fun. Thanks for the comment... updated the relevant error